# Issue with running .bash_profile by ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to export multiple variables through ansible. I have this task in my playbook

```
- name: Set the MIRA_ROOT and Binding_Address in Profile
  lineinfile: dest=/root/.bash_profile insertbefore='^export PATH' line="  {{item.line}}"
  with_items:
      - { line: 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk{{jdk_version}}' }
      - { line: 'export MIRA_ROOT=/opt/data/rg01/mira' }
```

How to run .bash_profile?I have written this code to run .bash_profile but it could not work

```
- name: Run the bash_profile
  shell: source /root/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 6):

What's your goal? Do you want to permanently set those vars or only for your ansible play? In any case `.bash_profile` probably is not the best solution.

Ansible initiates a new ssh connection for every task. If you'd source your `.bash_profile` in one task to set an environment var, in the next task it wouldn't be available.

If you want to set it permanently, you can write it to `/etc/environment`, with the `lineinfile` module just like you did.

If you only want to set it for the tasks of the Ansible play, you can [set it in your playbook](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_environment.html#setting-the-environment-and-working-with-proxies):

```
- hosts: ...
  environment:
    JAVA_HOME: /usr/java/jdk{{jdk_version}}
    MIRA_ROOT: /opt/data/rg01/mira
  tasks: ...
  roles: ...
```

Comment: I want to set the variable permanently and I tried in /etc/environment but it couldn't work.Please help me out with example