# Ansible and environment vars

Tags: vagrant, ansible

My ansible playbook reboot  virtual machine (vagrant,VB). Before rebooting i write code to .bashrc file of default vagrant user. But next task after   reboot work in env without vars in .bashrc. When i execute vagrant ssh -- all ok,.bashrc vars load in env

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with running .bash\_profile by ansible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268224/issue-with-running-bash-profile-by-ansible)

Answer (score 0):

When running the playbook, you need to use the environment module to set these values.

Most modules aren't pulling the environment variables similar to what you would do via SSH under a shell.

For Example:

```
copy: src=foo dest=bar
  environment:

  JAVA_HOME: /path/to/location
```